# How to make JSONIX tolerate extra XML elements on deserialization?

Tags: javascript, xml, json, jsonix

I'm using JSONIX 2.0.12 and it's awesome.

I have a large XML file for which I only care to deserialize a subset of elements to JSON.

When I leave some elements out of my mapping file, jsonix complains with an unexpected element error when deserializing.

Is there a way to have jsonix only pay attention to elements declared in my mapping and ignore the rest of the xml?

Answer (score 1):

Jsonix author here. Thank you for your feedback. :)

Please file an issue [here](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/issues), this is a reasonable request, I'll implement this.

Right now you can work around this by adding an [any element](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/JSNX/User+Guide#UserGuide-Anyelementproperty) property:

```
{
    type: 'classInfo',
    localName: 'MyType',
    propertyInfos: [{
        type: 'anyElement',
        name: 'catchAll',
        collection: true
    }]
}
```

This property will get all the "unknown" elements. This is not *exactly* what you want as the elements are not ignored and you have to add this property everywhere. Just a workaround. Please file an issue, I'll get it done in 2.1.1.

BTW, 2.1.0 was [released](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/releases/tag/2.1.0) few weeks ago.

**Update**

This is [fixed](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/issues/35) in 2.1.1 (yet to be released).